# Pairing display: flex with display: block and display: none

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I'm using pure JS and flexbox to create grid for my project.

Parts of the project are hidden with display: none at page load, but after clicking the button it should toggle between display none and block.

Sadly this completely either ruins display: flex or does not toggle. Is there any way to make these 2 properties work together?

Here is JSfiddle i put together
https://jsfiddle.net/c3dw0woa/

```
<div class="container">
<div>Text hello I was hidden</div>
</div>

<button class="dis_legend">Click to display</button>
```

CSS

```
.container{
 display: flex;
}
```

JS

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.style.display = "none";

var legend_button = document.querySelector('.dis_legend');

var container_displayed = false;
container.style.display = "none";

legend_button.onmousedown = function(){
if(legend_displayed == false){
    container.style.display = "block";
    container_displayed = true;
} else {
    container_displayed.display = "none";
    container_displayed = false;
}
}
```

Comment: If your container is display: flex, why are you toggling it between none and block? Shouldn't you be toggling it between none and flex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You an always use `display= flex` in js, to avoid the problem

I changed a few things in your javascript code

**See result:**

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var legend_button = document.querySelector('.dis_legend');

var container_displayed = false;
container.style.display = "none";

legend_button.onmousedown = function() {
  if (container_displayed == false) {
    container.style.display = "flex";
    container_displayed = true;
  } else {
    container.style.display = "none";
    container_displayed = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Text hello I was hidden</div>
</div>

<button class="dis_legend">Click to display</button>
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I also just saw that I made disgusting typo in the JS code. But it still wouldnt run because I never realised that display: flex also basically means that it is actually displayed. Good to know.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Chiller's solution should work, but here's another option in case you want to do it with an event listener:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.style.display = "none";

var legend_button = document.querySelector('.dis_legend');

var container_displayed = false;
container.style.display = "none";

legend_button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if (container.style.display == "none"){
        container.style.display = "block";
            } else {
      container.style.display = "none";
      }
})
```

Comment: tested it, also works, but I prefer Chiller's version :) Thank you anyway for your time!